# linux/ip6.h and netinet/in.h header can't be included simultaneously

Tags: c, linux, toolchain

I am using codesourcery arm toolchain 2009q1-203 on Linux platform 2.6.32.
It seems that there is a toolchain bug with `linux/in6.h` and `netinet/in.h` header files that contain the same definitions and cannot be included simultaneously.

```
/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include/linux/in6.h:47: error: conflicting types for 'in6addr_any'

/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include/netinet/in.h:211: error: previous declaration of 'in6addr_any' was here
```

What is the best approach to solve this?

- Exclude common definitions from one of the include files (via delete duplicate lines or Include guards)?
- Upgrade toolchain to newer version which hopefully provides a fix?
- Any other idea?

Comment: What are the types in question?  Do they perhaps share common fields, but one has some extra fields the other doesn't?  I can tell you that libtz handles this by redefining symbols around the include, e.g., `#define in6addr_any FOO_in6addr_any` / `#include <linux/in6.h>` / `#undef in6addr_any`.

Comment: The types in question are i.e in6addr_any and in6addr_loopback

Comment: The `linux/*` headers are *kernel* headers.  `netinet/in.h` is a C library header.  You're not meant to use both, at least not directly.  Unless you're writing a kernel module, your code should not include `linux/in6.h`.  On the other hand, if you are writing a kernel module then you must not use `netinet/in.h`.

Comment: We solved this in a way similar to cxw comment, not very elegant but it works.
#include <netinet/in.h>
#define in6addr_any FOO_in6addr_any
#define in6addr_loopback FOO_in6addr_loopback
#include <linux/ip6.h>
Thank you.